# How to update a single data point in d3 without touching other elements?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I would like to update a single data point and modify only the element that it was bound to, but I can't figure out how to do this.

[This article](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221) seems to indicate that `var sel = svg.selectAll(...).data(...)` gives a selection of updated data, then `sel.enter(...)` represents the new data, and afterwards `sel` represents both updated+new data together.

In [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/by38rLdv/2/), I am coloring new elements as green and updated elements as blue, but it seems *every* existing element gets colored as blue, rather than just the ones which changed since the last update. How can I update a single piece of data?

```
// ...

function update() {
    // clear old classes
    svg.selectAll("text").attr("class","");

    // join to the new data
    var sel = svg.selectAll("text").data(things);

    // update -- but this actually affects all elements in the selection?
    sel.attr("class","update");

    // enter
    sel.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class","enter")
        .attr("x", function(d,i) { return 20*i; })
        .attr("y", 20);

    // update + enter
    sel.text(function(d) { return d; });

    // exit
    sel.exit().remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, the "update" selection includes all existing elements, ready to update, regardless of whether or not the data has actually changed.

If you want to test to see if the new data is the same or different from the old data, you need a way to preserve the old data to compare with the new.  Then you can use a selection filter to discard elements where the data is the same.

I've discussed this issue [previously on the d3 mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/d3-js/w11PXct8jPI/discussion).  This is the approach I came up with:

```
selection = selection.property(" __oldData__", function(d){ return d; } ); 
  //store the old data as a property of the node
                    .data(newData);  
  //over-write the default data property with new data

selection.enter() /*etc*/;  //handle new elements

selection.filter( function(d) {    
  //test whether the relevant properties of d match the equivalent in the oldData
  //also test whether the old data exists, to catch the entering elements!
                 return ( (this.__oldData__ ) && 
                          (d.value != this.__oldData__.value) );
            })
            .style("fill", "blue");

selection.property("__oldData__", null);     
  //delete the old data once it's no longer needed
```

You can of course use any name for the old data property, it's just convention to throw a lot of "_" characters around it to avoid messing up any of the browser's native DOM properties.  You don't need to delete the oldData afterwards (it will just be over-written next time you update), but if you update infrequently it can save memory to explicitly release it.

Be aware that `selection.filter()` does not preserve index values.  If you need to keep track of `i`, you can either add an extra step to save the index before filtering as a separate property (of the element or of the data object), or you can skip the filter and just do the test directly in a function within the style/attr call.

**Edit:** I've changed the filter function, relative to the linked discussion, so that it *only* includes updated elements, not new *or* updated elements.  Either way, the filter selects the elements for which the filter function returns true.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Perhaps a more efficient way of updating single elements would be to keep a back-reference to the element in the data object itself? Something like `.enter().call(function(d) { d.elem = this; })`?

Comment: Sure.  If you already have the updated data objects filtered out from the rest, you could work from there.  The method above assumes you have a complete array of data objects, some of which may match the old data and some of which don't.

Comment: Also thanks for the link to the mailing list — that seems to be a more thorough discussion of what I want to do. I'm thinking of putting together a slightly different architecture, where data flows from an individual datum out to all of the elements it's bound to.

Comment: Be aware that in the above example you create `" __oldData__"` property for the selection different from one you delete this property, since some items can be moved to the `exit` selection.

Comment: @jtbandes, in general, `d3.js` isolates `data` from the `view`. What you suggested is to introduce such dependency. This may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, figuring this out is relatively easy. You're setting the text of the elements to the data, so all you need to do is compare that when deciding whether the data has been updated:

```
sel.classed("update", function(d) { return d != d3.select(this).text(); });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/by38rLdv/4/). For a general solution, see AmeliaBR's answer.

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but this doesn't fix the problem. Actually, I *want* to update the data in-place, so the default key function is correct. But either way, it seems that *all* elements are selected after `.data(...)`, rather than just the updated ones (so all elements are colored blue). This seems to go against what is claimed in Mike Bostock's article.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. If you're passing three data elements, then all of the existing three DOM elements are updated as there is new data matched to them. So what you're seeing is exactly what I'd expect to happen.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps a misunderstanding on my part. I was under the impression that `.data(...)` would do a diff between the old and new data. I guess this is incorrect?

Comment: The only part of the data that D3 sees is what you give it through the key function. This is only used for finding matching elements -- no "diff" as such is done.

Comment: Also, the "update" selection is perhaps misleadingly named here -- it doesn't really refer to changed data, but DOM elements that need to be updated as opposed to being added (entered) or removed (exited).

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's helpful. I've updated my question to be clearer about what I want (hopefully).